# Problem with vim when logged in as root

Tags: vim, sudo, root, vimrc

When I login as root or edit a file by `sudo` mode all of the options in my `/etc/vimrc` are not working (e.g. highlight line-number etc.)

Comment: Does user `root` have a `vimrc`?

Comment: i config at /etc/vimrc

Comment: What does `:echo $VIM` (in `vim`) tell you?  (According to my understanding of `:help system-vimrc`, the global `vimrc` is expected to be `$VIM/vimrc`)

Comment: $VIM is /usr/share/vim

Comment: You could try placing a copy of your `vimrc` in `/usr/share/vim/` (while I do not understand why `/etc/vimrc` is read at all when `vim` is started by a normal user)

Comment: Some distros set up `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` as a symlink to `/etc/vim/vimrc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the reason is that your home directory `~` is changed, where contains vim configuration file `.vimrc` .

Normally `~` is `/root` if you login as root, and  is `/home/YOURNAME` if you login as YOURNAME.

Comment: i'm config option in /etc/vimrc.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are using `vi` to try to start VIM which will not use `/etc/vimrc`.

If that is the case, you have two options:

1. Use `vim`
2. Modify `/etc/profile.d/vim.sh` to set `vi` as an alias for all users not only for users with a `uid` >= `100`

Answer (score 1):

Which `vimrc` are you talking about? I don't use/know `vim`, but in many cases `rc` files have two kinds of "incarnation": a system-wide `rc`-file under `/etc` that dictates the system defaults for the application and user-wide `rc`-files under the user homedirs, where users set their own settings, that override the defaults from the system-wide configuration file.

Meanwhile, there is `sudo`, that runs a program as another user (usually `root`, maybe, like `su`, it allows you to impersonate users other than `root`).

As you're running `vim` through `sudo`, my guess is that you're expecting `~/.vimrc` to be something that it isn't. Either that, or you don't understand what is `sudo` doing when you invoke it.

If it really is `~/.vimrc`, then it's not "not working", it's actually working quite well, the issue is that there's probably no `~root/.vimrc`, or it exists with different settings than these you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

This appears a result of introducing the additional hard-coded "default" vimrc in the newer versions of vim as `/usr/share/vim/vimXY/defaults.vim`.

https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2917#issuecomment-389203845

Until this is fixed, I see the only work-around in creating per-user `~/.vimrc` files (including `/root/.vimrc`).

Answer (score 0):

You should log in as root and `ls -al` you can see that there is no `.vimrc` ,so you can create a new `.vimrc` when you log as root. And now try it, everything is ok!